# Right syntax for requests.get (python library) to access github enterprise accounts

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I am working with python 2.7 + a couple of python libraries (requests & github3), in order to access my enterprise github account and manipulate some url webhooks.

The username / token I am using to access github is from a company (github enterprise account).

Next, the details of the python code, and the error messages that I am receiving:

```
oauth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
username = 'ENTERPRISE_GITHUB_USERNAME'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(oauth_token.rstrip())}
url='https://MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN/api/v3/repos/GITHUB_ORG/GITHUB_REPO/hooks'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, oauth_token.rstrip()), \ headers=headers)

('Response: ', <Response [404]>)
'{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com \ /enterprise/2.12/v3/repos/hooks/#list-hooks"}'
```

If I remove the username (since I am using the token), I receive this error message:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=(oauth_token.rstrip()), headers=headers)

{TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'}
```

---

I have already discarded some error with the token, because actually it works when I try to query other info. For example, to get a list of repositories.

Example:

oauth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
organization='MY_ORGANIZATION' github3.enterprise_login(token=oauth_token.rstrip(),url='https://MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN')
response = github_v3.repositories_by(organization)

output: It works! (the output lists the repositories of the organization "MY_ORGANIZATION").

So, it is because I have discarded the token as the root cause.

I think that probably the root cause might be related to the syntax of the "requests.get" sentence. I meant, since the username / token is an enterprise one, the syntax could be different (but I don't know how to write it).

On the other hand, if I use my personal github account / token, it works. So, it is because I think that the "requests.get" syntax should be a little different, when we use enterprise github accounts and publics (free) accounts.

For example:

To set up the "gh_login" variable for an enterprise account, I use:

```
gh_login = github3.enterprise_login(token=oauth_token.rstrip(),url='https://MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN')
```

But, for a public (free) github account, I would use:

```
gh_login = github3.login(token=oauth_token.rstrip())
```

Both of them works !

Therefore returning to the subject of requests.get, my current syntax actually **works** for a public (free) github account:

```
url='https://api.github.com/repos/GITHUB_ORG/GITHUB_REPO/hooks'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, oauth_token.rstrip()), headers=headers)
```

But if I use the enterprise domain, it doesn't:

```
url='https://MY_CORPORATE_DOMAIN/api/v3/repos/GITHUB_ORG/GITHUB_REPO/hooks'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, oauth_token.rstrip()), headers=headers)
```

Note that in both cases, the syntax of "requests.get" is the same.

Finally, I have already read the official documentation (REST API v3) for enterprise accounts, but I haven't found the right syntax:

https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.13/v3/enterprise-admin/

What could be the right syntax of the requests.get (for enterprise github accounts) to solve the above error messages ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform that I have already found the root cause (and solution) for the error message **404 not found**.

Basically, it was because the token was not created with the permission **admin:repo_hook**. So, I created a new token with that permission, and everything works smoothly.

I found that info in the following link:
https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/155

thanks,